# why are table cells different size despite same content?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with two rows and three columns. The two right cells are smaller in width than the two left ones. Why is this? The content is the same in both. Thx for help.

```
<div id="tableContain">
    <div id="tabRow1">
        <div id="tabCell">The gibberish (nonsense text) presented here </div>
        <div id="tabCell"> <img src="images/Flora/tree-of-life.jpg" /> </div>
        <div id="tabCell">The gibberish (nonsense text) presented here </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tabRow2">
        <div id="tabCell">The gibberish (nonsense text) presented here </div>
        <div id="tabCell"> <img src="images/Flora/tree-of-life.jpg" /> </div>
        <div id="tabCell">The gibberish (nonsense text) presented here </div>
    </div>
</div>

#tableContain {
    display: table;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

#tabRow1, #tabRow2 {
    display: table-row;
}

#tabCell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    padding: 10px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

img {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Id's are supposed to be unique. If you want for certain styles to apply to many elements, use `.tabcell` in your CSS definitions, and `<div class="tabcell">` in your HTML.

Comment: I forgot to define the cells as "class," but why does it matter? Does the use of "id" cause a conflict?

Comment: Set a width in tabCell if you want a width specified.  Otherwise its created dynamically.

Comment: In css, no. But if you try and use javascript, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I added `width: 33%;` to `#tabCell`. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v55jeg55/)**

This makes all the columns equal in width.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this.**

```
#tabRow1, #tabRow2 {
display: table-row;
 width: 600px;}
```